# Compare 1st then 2nd then 3rd column of Text File

Tags: c#

I'm making a Quizlet Type program and need help comparing text files. I have written

```
Hello, Hallo
Dog, Hund
Cat, Katze
```

That is my Text file. I want my program to compare 1st column

```
Hello, Hallo
```

And then after that comparison

```
Dog, Hund
```

and after that

```
Cat, Katze
```

As you see here I wrote code that compares the first row to the second row. But after that, it just doesn't compare to the second column of the file. I need help comparing to 2nd column then 3rd etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test32
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\akred\Desktop\testfall2\testfall2\Eng.txt";
            bool wantstoguess = true;
            int attempt = 0;
            bool win = false;
            int row = 0;

            List<engword> word = new List<engword>();
            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                string[] entries = line.Split(',');

                engword newWord = new engword();
                
                //Ew = Englisches Wort
                //REw = Richtig Englisches Wort bzw richtige übersetzung
                newWord.Ew = entries[0].Trim();
                newWord.REw = entries[1].Trim();

                word.Add(newWord);
            }
            
            foreach (var engword in word)
            {
                do
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("What is " + $"{engword.Ew }" + " in English");
                        attempt++;
                        string guessed = Console.ReadLine();

                        try
                        {
                            if (guessed == $"{ engword.REw }")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                                win = true;
                                ++row;
                            }
                            else if ($"{ engword.REw }" != guessed)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please Write a word");
                        }
                    } while (win == false);

                    if (win == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You gave guessed it!");
                        Console.Write("It took you " + attempt + " attempts!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    Console.Write("Do you want to continue? [Yes/No]?");

                    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (answer == "Yes")
                        wantstoguess = true;

                    win = false;

                    if (answer == "No")
                        wantstoguess = false;

                } while (wantstoguess == true);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it out and it seems to work okay. The only thing I noticed is that the `attempt` doesn't reset per word. Moving it inside of the `foreach (var engword in word)` loop fixes that and then it works fine (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/enV8K.png). What issue exactly are you seeing? Could you maybe describe the steps of the input that you're using? Or add a screenshot/snippet of the program output where it's not working?

Comment: Do you still have a pic of the code? Im very new to c# and dont know what the problem is.

Comment: I just used the code in your question and it worked

Comment: Thanks. Just cleared some things out. Can you please tell me where to put attempt_ i tried between foreach and do, between do and do it doesnt seem to wrok.

Comment: It depends on where you want to start counting the attempts from. If you put it just inside the `foreach` loop, then it will only reset on a new word. If you put it inside the first `do`/`while` then it will reset per round of each word

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are looking for a *Dictionary*, `Dictionary<string, string>`, e.g.

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  Dictionary<string, string> EnToDe = File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0].Trim(),
                  pair => pair[1].Trim(), 
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

You can easily create reversed German - English dictionary as well:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> DeToEn = EnToDe
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Value,
                  pair => pair.Key,
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Now you can easily get words

```
 List<string> englishWords = EnToDe.Keys.ToList();

 List<string> deutschWords = EnToDe.Keys.ToList();
```

and translation

```
string english = "CAT";

if (EnToDe.TryGetValue(english, out var deutsch))
  Console.Write($"English \"{english}\" is German \"{deutsch}\"");
else
  Console.Write($"Sorry, Engish \"{english}\" is not found in the dictionary");
```

**Edit:** If you want to implement some kind of test where student must translate each word from German into English, you can try a simple loop. First we prepare the words:

```
string[] germanWords = DeToEn
  .Keys
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()) // Shuffle
  .ToArray();

// words which are difficult to learn and thus should be tested again 
HashSet<string> wordsToRepeat = new HashSet<string>();
```

Then loop over these words:

```
foreach (string word in germanWords) {
  int attempt = 0;

  while (true) {
    attempt += 1;

    Console.WriteLine($"What is {word} in English?");
                    
    string guessed = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    if (string.Equals(guessed, DeToEn[word], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
      Console.WriteLine("You gave guessed it!");
      Console.WriteLine($"It took you {attempt} attempts!");

      break; 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");

    // If the word is too difficult to translate, it should appear again 
    if (attempt >= 3) // let word be difficult if it takes 3+ attempt to guess it
      wordsToRepeat.Add($"{word},{DeToEn[word]}");
  }

  Console.Write("Do you want to continue? [Yes/No]?");

  string answer = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

  if (string.Equals(answer, "N", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
      string.Equals(answer, "NO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    break;
}

File.WriteAllLines("c:\WordsToRepeat.txt", wordsToRepeat);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But I dont know how to implement this into my code. Can you help me please. Just started with c# few days ago dont know much.

Comment: @KhangC21: if you want to implement a kind of tester for a German speaking student to learn English, I think you should 1. Extract all german words from dictionary and shuffle them. 2. Loop over these words 3. For each word keep asking student to translate (guess) the word, 4. When translation is correct one, show the number of attempts. 5. Finally, ask studend if (s)he wans to continue. Please, see my edit

Comment: Thanks. I wanted that the students guessed the words in a row. And string a 2nd File to the Code and when the word is written incorrectly, it adds that line to the second file and then the students would repeat the words they got wrong at the end. Im not really sure how i would do that. Here is my Code. https://gist.github.com/Khang21/27c013a52f0eed13637c492e23462cf7
Please take a look and if possible tell me what i could do next.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dictionary<string, string> instead of List. Then key of dictionary will be english word and value will be german word.

After you build dictionary from txt file you have to loop the dictionary keys (english words) and you have to compare user's input with dictionary value of current key.

```
// firstly you have to build dictionary similar this
string filepath = @"C:\Users\akred\Desktop\testfall2\testfall2\Eng.txt";

Dictionary<string, string> myDict = File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(words => words[0].Trim(), words => words[1].Trim());

foreach(var item in myDict)
{
    // here you have to implement loop for user's input and comparing with value

    Console.WriteLine($"What is { item.key } in english?");
    string guessed = Console.ReadLine();

    if (guessed == item.value)
    {
        // OK
    }
    else
    {
        // fail
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I form this around to read from textfile?

Comment: I have edited my previous code. Look over there but I didn't try to compile it.

Comment: Wow thanks. This from professional written code is way shorter than mine and works exactly the same. Im so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is structured is a bit confusing, but if you see what it is actually doing it will be

```
for each word
{
    until the user opts out
    {
        until the answer is correct
        {
            try to guess    
        }
    }
}
```

Which means you never get to the next word unless the user says they don't want to continue. A better way would be do something like

```
for each word
{
    until the answer is correct
    {
        try to guess
    }
    if(does not want to continue)
        break; 
}
```

Here *break* will get you out of the *for each word* loop

UPDATE

If I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve, you should end up with something like

```
foreach (var engword in word)
        {
           // do --> remove this
           // {--> remove this
                do
                {
                   ...
                } while (win == false);

                if (win == true)//this check is unnessesary, you won't get here unless win is true
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You gave guessed it!");
                    Console.Write("It took you " + attempt + " attempts!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.Write("Do you want to continue? [Yes/No]?");

                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
               
                //Add this
                if (answer == "No")
                {
                    Console.Write("Okay, bye!");
                    break;
                }

                win = false;

             //   if (answer == "No")--> remove this
             //       wantstoguess = false;--> remove this

            //} while (wantstoguess == true); --> remove this
        }
```

Comment: Where should i add this to? So sorry for bothering

Comment: Updated, let me know if it helps :)